# QML: programmatically update binding

Tags: qt, binding, qml

Is there a way of programmatically updating (i.e. reevaluating) the current binding of a property (without setting it to something else and resetting it)?

Comment: What you want to do with that?

Comment: I have an unfortunate dependency chain where I listen to changes for a property P in both a change handler H and a binding B, and the change handler expects that the binding has already been reevaluated, but due to the way QML orders the actions, H is called before B is updated. I could work around the problem in a lot of ways, but simply reevaluating the binding in-situ would have the least impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (hack that should be avoided if possible):

```
value: foo, bindedValue
```

or

```
value: (foo && !foo) || bindedValue
```

`value` will be completely reevaluated when calling the following function  `reevaluateValue()`:

```
property bool foo: false

function reevaluateValue() {
    foo = !foo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your binding looks something like this:

```
foo: bar
```

change it to this:

```
foo: { baz; bar }
```

where `baz` is something that changes often enough to cause `foo` to be re-evaluated when you need it to, which implies that `baz` would be related. Similar hacks have been done [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Slider.qml#n187), for example.

I would recommend fixing the issue properly by not relying on the order of evaluation.